# Move file that aged

Tags: php

So I managed to get all files in my directory using this:

```
$dir   = PUBLIC_DIRECTORY . '/' . $login_session . '/';
$files = array();
$DirectoryIterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir);
$IteratorIterator  = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($DirectoryIterator, RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
foreach ($IteratorIterator as $file) {
    $path = $file;
    if ($file->isFile()) 
        $files[] = realpath($path);
}
```

which resulted to this:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\fms\public\kei\docx\FMS.docx
C:\xampp\htdocs\fms\public\kei\jpg\1.jpg
```

Now i used the code below which should move the files from inside their directory to C:\xampp\htdocs\fms\public\kei\Bin\ when aged

```
foreach($files as $f) {
    if (filemtime($f) < time() - 86400) {
        rename($f, realpath($dir . "/Bin/" . basename($f));
    }
}
```

but nothing happens for some reasons. I tried different things to get the filename like...

```
echo realpath($dir . "/Bin/") . basename($f);
```

but this code shows

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\fms\public\kei\BinFMS.docx
C:\xampp\htdocs\fms\public\kei\Bin1.jpg
```

Comment: Hi! If you notice `$f` is full path of the file because of `foreach($files as $f)`

Answer (score -1):

I managed to fixed it by doing this

$bin = "\Bin\";

and this `rename($f, realpath($dir) . $bin . basename($f));`